# Adding a collection to a document in Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The way I have my file structure set up right now is that I have a main folder calles users. In that folder we have a document with a randomly generated name that contain some information along with another folder for files. I would like to duplicate this only using code. I could either run a function to build a template from scratch, or build a function to duplicate a file along with its subfolders.
Fyi, the file tree goes as such - [users] -> [user_document/user_information] -> [images]

I have yet to find any resources about this online, or maybe I'm not looking in the right areas, either ways, thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI Firestore doesn't have anything called folders or files. It only has collections and documents within those collections. I suggest you make an attempt at solving this problem and editing the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect along with your debugging observations. What you're stating now is difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new document to a collection, use the add method on a CollectionReference:

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

firestore()
  .collection('Users')
  .add({
     image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/10640445/pexels-photo-10640445.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User added!');
  });
```

The add method adds the new document to your collection with a random unique ID. If you'd like to specify your own ID, call the set method on a DocumentReference instead:

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

firestore()
  .collection('Users')
  .doc('ABC')
  .set({
    image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/10640445/pexels-photo-10640445.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User added!');
  });
```

For more details refer to the [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage)

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I asked the wrong question. How can I add a Collection within a document? You can do it using the firebase widgets on their website, but I would like to do it using code. Thank you, sorry for not asking the right question in the first place.

Comment: Refer to this [site](https://dev.to/rossanodan/how-to-fetch-subcollections-from-cloud-firestore-with-react-3n93)